# Python Discord.py bot assign role to user in server when command is in DM

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to get a bot in a server that gives a user a certain role when it is dm'ed. Right now I only have it working for when the command is used in the server. Is there a way to get it in the dm channel?

```
@client.command(brief="Sets favorite programming language", description="Set a role as either Python, C++, C#, or Java",
                aliases=["lang"])
async def language(ctx, lang=""):
    if isinstance(ctx.channel, discord.DMChannel):
        if lang.lower() not in ["python", 'c++', 'java', 'c#']:
            await ctx.send("The available languages are Python, C++, C#, and Java.")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Your role is now " + lang.lower().capitalize() + ".")
            await ctx.message.add_reaction("")
            role = get(client.get_guild(guild_id).roles, name=lang.lower().capitalize())
            print(ctx.message.author.guild(guild_id).roles)
            roles = [role for role in ctx.message.author.roles if role.name in ['C++', "Java", 'Python', 'C#']]
            await ctx.message.author.remove_roles(*roles)
            await ctx.message.author.add_roles(role)
```

Answer (score 0):

You require to found the guild you want to give the rule to the user in that guild.

If your bot is a private bot for one server you can get the server id and use `client.get_guild(id)` and use the guild as reference or if your bot is a public bot which will be used in several servers you should add another argument as guild ID which should be provided by the user.

If you are going to make a private bot so here is your edited code:

```py
@client.command(brief="Sets favorite programming language", description="Set a role as either Python, C++, C#, or Java",
                aliases=["lang"])
async def language(ctx, lang=""):
    guild_id = 123456789   # Replace it with yours
    if lang.lower() not in ["python", 'c++', 'java', 'c#']:
        await ctx.send("The available languages are Python, C++, C#, and Java.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Your role is now "+lang.lower().capitalize()+".")
        await ctx.message.add_reaction("ðŸ‘Œ")
        role = get(client.get_guild(guild_id).roles, name=lang.lower().capitalize())
        roles = [role for role in ctx.message.author.roles if role.name in ['C++', "Java", 'Python', 'C#']]
        await ctx.message.author.remove_roles(*roles)
        await ctx.message.author.add_roles(role)
```

If you are making a public bot

```py
@client.command(brief="Sets favorite programming language", description="Set a role as either Python, C++, C#, or Java",
                aliases=["lang"])
async def language(ctx, *args):
    lang = args[0]
    guild = client.get_guild(int(args[1])) if isinstance(ctx.channel, discord.DMChannel) else ctx.guild
    if lang.lower() not in ["python", 'c++', 'java', 'c#']:
        await ctx.send("The available languages are Python, C++, C#, and Java.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Your role is now "+lang.lower().capitalize()+".")
        await ctx.message.add_reaction("ðŸ‘Œ")
        role = get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name=lang.lower().capitalize())
        roles = [role for role in guild.get_member(ctx.author.id).roles if role.name in ['C++', "Java", 'Python', 'C#']]
        await ctx.message.author.remove_roles(*roles)
        await ctx.message.author.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: On your first solution I think ctx.author.roles doesn't work. I get discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'roles'

Comment: @JohnHenry5 my bad ☺ I fogot to change that which I did just now

Comment: Well thiss solution is supoosed to work in the dm channel. If you see above, I put an if statement if isinstance(ctx.channel, discord.DMChannel): to check if its in the dm channel. I'm using your solution in the "private" bot and it doesn't work. I need to somehow get the reference to that same user in the server id iI have.